# How to remove computed padding from ion-button when it is disabled

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

Ionic Button, when disabled appears like it have two background colors in IOS.
I am using ionic button with disabled property like this

```
<ion-button expand="full" type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid (click)="login()">Login</ion-button>
```

Here is how it looks when -

Form is Invalid

[image]

Form is valid

[image]

On inspecting i found, it’s the COMPUTED padding-inline-start: 16px; and padding-inline-end: 16px; that is causing this kind of background;

I am not using any extra css styling on the button. And this kind of background is visible only when you build the app for ios and run it into simulator or device.

So, How to remove that padding ?

Comment: add css rule that will be saying - when button is disabled remove padding

Comment: @Yuriy Thanks for replying but there is no extra css added when button is disabled. It's the computed styling that is kind of added to DOM when page is loaded. I tried setting those property in css but it does nothing.

Comment: You can use attribute binding. It will be like [class.disabled]="!loginForm.valid ", where disabled will a class with padding:0px, which you need to define in scss.

Comment: Thank you @SarathMohandas, I have already mentioned it's the computed style that is causing this kind of behavior. I have tried it already, But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use ngClass combined with a css class:

`[ngClass]="!loginForm.valid? 'no-start-end-padding'"`.

In the css class add `!important` to overwrite the 16px start and end padding values.

```
.no-start-end-padding {
    padding-inline-start: 16px !important; 
    padding-inline-end: 16px !important;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried all these things with css. Nothing works. This kinda background appears only on devices not in browser.